# knockout validation ignores errorsAsTitle config for input field

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using knockout (3.0.0) with validation (1.0.2), trying to disable "tooltips" which ko-validation generates for a field when it contains an error:

[image]

Based on [documentation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration), `errorsAsTitle:false` should prevent tooltips from displaying, but it seems to ignore `false`.

[Fiddle illustrating the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/SAFX/q4QCY/55/)

My current configuration

```
  ko.validation.rules.required.message = 'Field(s) are required!';

  ko.validation.configure({
      registerExtenders: true,
      messagesOnModified: true,
      errorsAsTitle: false,  //<-----problem here
      insertMessages: false,
      decorateElement: true,
      errorElementClass: 'inputError'
  });

  function ViewModel() {
      this.name = ko.observable("").extend({
          required: true
      });
  };

  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 2):

on the lastest version use `decorateInputElement` instead of `decorateElement`

Comment: You mean v1.0.2? I usually get from CDN, there's no diff with release version from github, right?

Comment: Seems like the latest version has decorateInputElement

Answer (score 1):

Works with latest version on github

http://jsfiddle.net/q4QCY/56/

```
Version on that cdn is old
```

Comment: What version of ko validation is that?

Comment: Latest build from github